# Add PNG to .jasper file on runtime

Tags: jasper-reports

I was tasked with making an aplication that adds PNG of peoples signatures to some documents, so every time someone uploads a signatre to the system the aplication adds that PNG to the PDF that gets renderen in the .jasper file.

I am being given 5 .jasper files which are the documents that need the signature to be added to them, but reading about Jasper the .jasper files are the compiled forms of the documents and if I want to modify them in any way I need the .jrxml files.

Do I need to ask for the jrxml files? or is it possible to add the signatures in run time to the PDF by having the aplication interact with the .jasper file?

I believe that at the very least, the function that triggers the PDF rendering should recive a PNG of the signature in order to add it to the PDF, meaning the .jasper file should already have a parameter where the PNG would be loaded into already set up them, so that way I would not have to modify the .jasper file and I would just call the function that renders and pass the PNG though it.

If that is the case how could I verify that the .jasper file has this parameter set up already?

Comment: 1) You can use JasperReports API for building report on fly 2) You can pass parameter and use it at printWhenExpression to hide/show image

Comment: @AlexK 1)but do I need the .jrxml file to do so? or do the .jasper files work for with the API?

2) since I was given the Jasper file the parameter should exist already inside the jasper file doesnt it?

Comment: 1) As you wish. You can build report from Java code without using template. Or you can use template 2) Yes, the parameter and expression should be there

Answer (score 0):

I would add the signatures dynamically in the jrxml file like:

```
        <image>
            <reportElement x="96" y="42" width="50" height="50" uuid="eda533e7-0d2f-4df0-8ef1-b3cce6a63936"/>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA["pic_"+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+".jpg"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

so the right picture will be chosen on the fly. For sure you have to change the jrxml files one time. But afterwards this is only a configuration task. Think you add the name below the signature as well. So you should have a method to dynamically create text out of the base data.